# How to send file via FTP and bypass the quota limit?

Tags: php, ftp, limit

On my server there are limit of max 2MB file sended by FTP. If I send it by some script in PHP, there are no restriction, and I want to send something around 3.8MB.
Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "by some script in PHP"? Do you mean you are sending it to a PHP script using a web browser? If so, the PHP script likely has a file size limit, too, but much larger than 2MB.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more info on your problem?
You can't compress it or split it?

Comment: something like tiny upload script will do it I think

Comment: You cannot exceeed the 2MB FTP quota. It does not matter whether you are attempting to do it manually through a FTP client or through some script, that speaks the FTP protocol.

If you could exceed the quota, then the FTP server would be buggy, no?

If you are doing the upload through some script, then it probably is simply NOT using FTP.

Comment: Could you please provide the PHP script that worked for you? If it works, then it'll probably have all the clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a program that could split any file into pieces, it is called Hjsplit(here is the link: freebyte.com/hjsplit). once you have splitted the file and uploaded it onto the server, there is a [php script](http://www.freebyte.com/hjsplit/#hjsplitphp) which lets you re-join the splitted file.

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes from my wild imagination, and not quite sure if its possible. I would try to get the content of the file and separating it into two, and then uploading the first file and then appending the content of the second file to the first one.

Example:

If the original file is:

0101010101010100101010

split it into two files:

File One:01010101010
File Two:10100101010

Upload the first file and then append file two.